# map making software - GIS

Tags: dictionary, gis

In my project i need to create a map with three layers, basic geographic layer at the bottom, a GSM coverage area layer in top of it, and then a location based services layer on top of it. after creation i have to navigate through the map and get the data of a location, longitude,latitude , GSM signal strength and the services available to that position. any one know a tool that i can use to develop such kind of map? if it is a open source one it is better?

thanx

Comment: What's your project? A web page? A desktop application? A smartphone app?

Comment: @Spacedman sorry for not mentioning it.. it is a desktop application!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Quantum GIS, an open-source GIS mapping package. It can load spatial data in various forms (points, lines, polygons, grids) and let you navigate and query them.

www.qgis.org, any questions would probably be better on the gis stackexchange site and not stackoverflow, since this isn't really a programming question any more.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. i will post it there! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) and to be honest, I did not and I will not regret my choice :)